# How to get screenshot with out perceived by monitor softwares in a secure computer

Tags: windows-7, screenshot

First, I don't want do bad things but just for fun.
Os is Win7, all computers are controlled by windows field, each computer has monitor software, I haven't administrator privilege. I want get screenshot frequently but not perceived by administrator. I have known that use PRINT_SCREEN key will perceived by monitor software easily. Is there any way to get screenshot? May be some system API or other software API?

Comment: Search for software that can do that, quite easy to find (like some popular image editor). If you actually want to write some code for fun, search for some tutorials, either way this is not the correct platform to ask this kind of questions, show us that you put some effort in it and present us your code if it doesn't work, but don't expect that someone will do all the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am not familiar with os and software. How to get screen frequently (may be 10 times one second), but not perceived by admin, I haven't the direction. I only want to get some tips, and I will try it myself.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a platform for general tips. Please search for tips on "the internet" and you will find stuff that helps you. If you have problems implementing a "tip" then you can post a question here :)